# mvc3 getting a DB model remove error

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am simply doing a database check to see if any rows are expired but I am getting a System.Data.Entity.Dbset error on  **db.servicers.Remove(servicer)** saying that piece of code has some invalid arguments .my little code is

```
var servicer = (from s in db.servicers where
                DateTime.Now >= s.expired select s).ToList();

        if (servicer.Any())
        {
            db.servicers.Remove(servicer);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The **expired** field is a datetime and I just want to loop the database and delete any record that expires today or that has expired; whats the best way to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Lews Therin said Remove takes a type T so you should enumerate your list.

```
var servicer = (from s in db.servicers where
                DateTime.Now >= s.expired select s).ToList();

    if (servicer.Any())
    {
        foreach(var s in servicer) 
        {
            db.servicers.Remove(s);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```